# How to create a thread that emulates the precision timing of a capture filter when producing audio data?

Tags: winapi, directshow, performancecounter

I have a DirectShow push source filter that accumulates data from custom audio streams that are *not* timestamped.  It buffers them, and then sends them to an external audio output device that accepts audio buffers via an HTTP server the device provides (you submit it audio buffers via HTTP).  The audio output device is unfortunately timing sensitive.  Sending it too much data at once or (naturally) too little data at a time confuses it and causes playback problems such as "stuttering".

I need to send it buffers over an HTTP connection at a precisely timed interval, just like the precision a capture device that uses hardware based sampling and clocking does when it publishes captured data.  I assume I have to create a real-time critical thread and use it.  Here are my questions:

1. How I should do the timing?  What Windows API calls and data structures do I use to do this correctly? Something using the Windows performance counter features?
2. How do I block when I am not ready to publish any data in my push source filter's FillBuffer() method?  Mutex?  Semaphore?
3. How do I avoid drift?  For example, if I need to generate a 50 millisecond buffer and I am emulating a sample rate of 8000, how do I make sure that I am not undershooting or overshooting the calculated publication time in a way that would accumulate over time, possibly leading to gaps in the audio?

Answer (score 0):

regarding the timing and the drifting; you could do the following:

- When you start streaming, store the current time in `StreamingPos`.
- Now each time when you send 50 ms, you increase the `StreamingPos` by 50ms.
- And don't send any further data before the current time has reached `StreamingPos`.

This way you will sync the datarate to your local systemtime. This does not need to match exactly the clock of the player device. But that should not be a problem. The only way to solve that is having both devices synchronised with the same timesource.